# What is TBD power, TBD power, TBD

Tags: power, voltage

I was reading up about a processor spec and I came across the acronym TBD.

On googling, i could only find only colloqual explanations, but nothing solid. Here is one research paper link (http://www.researchgate.net/publication/3065006_Experimental_evidence_of_TBD_power-law_for_voltage_dependence_of_oxide_breakdown_in_ultrathin_gate_oxides)

I am sorry for pasting link but i dont know how else to explain better.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While "TBD" can mean a range of things, and the usage in the article cited was very sloppy, in the context,  TBD stands for "time to breakdown".

A good example of the usage [is given here](http://libra.msra.cn/Publication/51019895/understanding-the-influence-of-antifuse-bitcell-dimensions-the-programming-time-and-energy-using-an)

- " ... Understanding the influence of antifuse bitcell dimensions the programming time and energy using an analytical model: ...   The model yields the **time-to-breakdown** and the wearout current as a function of the programming voltage and the dimensions of the antifuse bitcell. As a main result, it is demonstrated that a device with a small capacitor area exhibits shorter **TBD**, lower Iwearout, and hence a lower programming energy. Characterization and modeling are performed for a programming voltage range from 3.5V to 7V **with a minimum TBD of 9ns**. ..."

Answer (score 0):

In the spec I was reading, TBD was actually use for "Time to Break Down".

Thank you for your answers.